# Efficient way to lookup a value in Pandas from the same dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am in a situation that I want to lookup a value basis an ID column that belongs to both manager and an employee, something like a self join solution that I want to implement in Python.

So my data frame looks like this:

```
ID      ID1          ID2        ID1Info    ID2Info
1       1001         1002         a          b
1       1002         1003         b          c
1       1003         1002         c          b
1       1004         1001         f          a
1       1005         1001         e          a
1       1006         1002         d          b
```

Now the table is structured in a manner that ID1Info is based on the values in column ID1 and I want to create ID2Info column that will fetch the information for values in ID2 column whose values are given in ID1 column. Example : for ID1 = 1002 the ID1Info is b and hence wherever I see 1002 in ID2 column, my ID2Info column should populate "b" as the value . How should I achieve this in pandas?

Comment: Is ID1 duplicated in your DataFrame?

Comment: Nope.. ID1 is all unique and even ID2 is all unique.. you can think of ID1 like an employee and ID2 like a manager..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `.map()`:

```
df["ID2Info"] = df.ID2.map(dict(zip(df.ID1, df.ID1Info)))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   ID   ID1   ID2 ID1Info ID2Info
0   1  1001  1002       a       b
1   1  1002  1003       b       c
2   1  1003  1002       c       b
3   1  1004  1001       f       a
4   1  1005  1001       e       a
5   1  1006  1002       d       b
```